# If the domain has only monos, every conservative functor reflects split epis

Tags: category-theory, accessible-categories

I'm reading a paper on accessible categories where the authors remark that when the domain has only monos, any conservative, accessible functor reflects split epimorphisms as well. This seemed to be quite a simple result (for there was no proof nor reference), but I'm struggling to find a proof. The reference in question is Remark 3.5 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.2910). Could someone give me a hint or tell me if any additional hypotheses are needed?

---

EDIT: The functor $\mathcal{P}(X) \to \text{Set}$ taking the subset $A$ to the set $X/A$ where $A$ is collapsed to a point and the inclusion $A \subset B$ to the obvious map $X/A \to X/B$ seems to give a counterexample.

Comment: That does not sound plausible to me. Perhaps the authors meant to observe that in a category where every morphism is monic, split epimorphisms are the same as isomorphisms.

Comment: The problem is that this is used with sole assumption that the domain category has only monos, by a sort of pullback argument in 4.12. I think $\mathcal{P}(X) \to \text{Set}, A \mapsto X/A$ (collapsing the subset to a point) is a simple counterexample. I guess nevertheless one can get around without this degree of generality where this "fact" is applied, but I was curious if the statement held.

Comment: @ZhenLin oops, forgot to mention

Comment: @interregno You did not get the exact statement right: the statement is about split epis. So your counterexample does not work, but I think there still is an (even easier) counterexample: consider the category with two objects and just one arrow between them, together with the functor that sends that arrow to any split epi (say in the category of sets) that is not an iso.

Comment: Rereading your question made me realise that you probably just left out "split" in your question body, as it is in your title, and that your example is essentially a generalisation of mine (take $X$ to be a singleton), so it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A condition that would work is to require the functor to only have monos in its image. That is: if $F: \mathcal K \to \mathcal L$ is conservative and every arrow in its image is mono then $F$ reflects split epis. This is simply because then every split epi in its image will also be mono and hence iso, which is reflected because $F$ is conservative.

In the comments you mention how the problematic remark is used in 4.12 in the paper you linked. Indeed the relevant functor there does have only monos in its image (and similar for the use of the remark in 4.11). We will use the notation of 4.12 in the linked paper. The situation can be summarised in the diagram below, which is a pullback of categories:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathcal{K} @>H>> \mathbf{Set}\\
@A \bar{G} AA @AA G A \\
\mathcal{L} @>>\bar{H}> \mathbf{Emb}(\mathbf{Set})
\end{CD}
$$
Here $\mathbf{Emb}(\mathbf{Set})$ is the category of sets and injective functions, $G$ is the inclusion functor and $H$ is a faithful functor (anything else is irrelevant for this answer).

We need to show that $\bar G(f)$ is a mono for any arrow $f$ in $\mathcal L$. If not, then there are distinct $g$ and $h$ in $\mathcal K$ such that $\bar G(f)g = \bar G(f)h$. By faithfulness of $H$ we then have that $H \bar G(f)$ is not mono, as witnessed by $H(g)$ and $H(h)$. However, $H \bar G(f) = G \bar H(f)$ is in the image of $G$ and is thus mono because $G$ has only monos in its image by definition. We this arrive at a contradiction, and conclude that $\bar G(f)$ is mono.